# how validate data that is not send by Post method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have a static object in controller that will be fill in some level of registration forms.finally i want to validate this object by modelstate method but is not possible because that is not send by post method..i am searching a standard way to validate..

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private MyDb db = new MyDb();
    private static Trainer trainer = new Trainer();
    public Trainer InfoSave(Trainer info)
    {
        trainer.SchoolGrade = info.SchoolGrade;
        trainer.SchoolMajor = info.SchoolMajor;
        trainer.MajorId = info.Major.Id;
        trainer.History = info.History;
        trainer.Major = info.Major;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

}
```

Comment: Hi, How is the model send that you cannot use `ModelState` to validate it

Comment: hi,the model was created in controller and just fill by other actions data levels by level

Comment: Can you show the form you have.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some Third party library for loosely couple the validation logic. I am using FluentValidation library. You can utilize it:

```
using FluentValidation;

public class TrainerValidator : AbstractValidator<Trainer> {
  public TrainerValidator() {
    RuleFor(c=> c.Name).NotNull().WithMessage("Name is required");
  }
}

public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private MyDb db = new MyDb();
    private static Trainer trainer = new Trainer();
    public Trainer InfoSave(Trainer info)
    {
        trainer.SchoolGrade = info.SchoolGrade;
        trainer.SchoolMajor = info.SchoolMajor;
        trainer.MajorId = info.Major.Id;
        trainer.History = info.History;
        trainer.Major = info.Major;
        TrainerValidator validator = new TrainerValidator();
        ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(trainer);
        if (result.IsValid)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

}
```

You can extend it based on your requirements. Here is the link for the same [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/start)